# To get columns output in separate file

Tags: awk

I have a file and its content looks like:

```
abc=123|qwer=432|reiw=2344|xyz=123 445|tyu=23 rows
```

I have tried using `tr` and `sed` but I will need to use `awk`

The desired output should look like:

```
file2:
123|432|2344|123 445|23 rows
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -F'=|\|' -pe '$_ = join "|", grep { $k++ % 2 } @F'

sed -e 's/[^=|]*=//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tried with this `sed`:

```
sed 's/[a-z,=]//g' | sed 's/$/rows/'
```

That is, removing any character between "a" and "z" and also the "=". After that, append "rows" at the end.

This has only been tested with your example line, if there are some other variants in your file perhaps it won't work.

Another way with `awk` taking all the values between "=" and "|":

```
awk '$0=$2' FS=\= RS='|' ORS="|" | head -1
```

I had to pipe `head` because it got printed a final "|" character in a second line after the expected output.